# AutoIt - Navigate to ASP page that doesn't allow direct linking

Tags: autoit

Can anyone "translate" how to do this with AutoIt instead of Simpletest?

[Simpletest browser (php) on an asp site that doesn't allow direct linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284003/simpletest-browser-php-on-an-asp-site-that-doesnt-allow-direct-linking)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it:

```
#include <IE.au3>

$URL="http://www.acgme.org/adspublic/"
$MyIExplorer=_IECreate($URL,1,1,1,1)

Local $theFrame = _IEFrameGetObjByName($MyIExplorer,"control")

_IELinkClickByText($theFrame, "Sponsoring Institutions")

_IELoadWait($theFrame)
ConsoleWrite(_IEBodyReadHTML($theFrame))
```

Comment: Thanks again @Manadar, this AutoIt newbie is learning.  The `_IELinkClickByText` is a simple solution.